# Can i load images from the device's documents directory to AsyncImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

Actually, I am not sure about this but i have this condition where i check whether internet is available or not and accordingly load the image into AsyncImageView. It works fine when i load any image from the internet, but is it possible to load a local image to AsyncImageView?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView/) by Nick Lockwood? This is simply a category to UIImageView, so when you have the image already, why not set the image property directly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got the solution to this problem.All i did was this

```
 NSURL *theURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/gaurav/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/AC6E9B2E-DB25-4933-A338-755B134E1A61/Documents/Attachment290_294_1344928691.jpeg"];
    NSLog(@"local URl is::%@",theURL);
    [self.asyncimageview loadImageFromURL:theURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will help you.

1. Make a new file
2. Inherit from UIImageView
3. Copy/Paste the following code.

   ## import

   ## import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

   @interface AsynchronousImageView : UIImageView{
       NSMutableData *data;
       UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
       NSString *urlString; // key for image cache dictionary
       ASIHTTPRequest *requestLocal;
   }
   @property(nonatomic,assign) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

   - (void)loadImageFromURLString:(NSString *)theUrlString;
   - (void)loadImageFromNSURL:(NSURL *)theUrl;
   - (void)loadImageFromFile:(NSString *)filePath;
     -(void) showLoader;
     -(void) stopLoader;
     @end
4. Then In .m file paste the following.

   ## import "AsynchronousImageView.h"

   ## import "ASIDownloadCache.h"

   @implementation AsynchronousImageView
   @synthesize activityIndicator;

   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
     {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
         // Initialization code
         //[self setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
     }
     return self;
     }
     -(void)dealloc
     {
     if (requestLocal) {
         [requestLocal setDelegate:nil];
     }
     requestLocal = nil;
     activityIndicator = nil;
     [super dealloc];
     }
     /*
     // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
     // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
     {
     // Drawing code
     }
     */
     -(void) showLoader{
     if(activityIndicator == nil){
     activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
     [self addSubview:activityIndicator];
     activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f - activityIndicator.frame.size.width /2.0f, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f - activityIndicator.frame.size.height /2.0f, activityIndicator.frame.size.width, activityIndicator.frame.size.height);
     [activityIndicator release];
     }
     [activityIndicator startAnimating];
     }
     -(void) stopLoader{
     if(activityIndicator){
         [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
         [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
         activityIndicator = nil;
     }
     }
   - (void)loadImageFromFile:(NSString *)filePath {
     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     [self setImage:img];
     [self stopLoader];
     }
   - (void)loadImageFromURLString:(NSString *)theUrlString
     {
     /*if (requestLocal) {
         [requestLocal setDelegate:nil];
     }*/
     requestLocal = nil;
         [self showLoader];
         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theUrlString];
         requestLocal = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
         [requestLocal setDelegate:self];
         [requestLocal setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed)];
         [requestLocal setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
         [requestLocal setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
         [requestLocal startAsynchronous];
     self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playerDefault.png"];
     }

   -(void)loadImageFromNSURL:(NSURL *)theUrl
   {
       if (requestLocal) {
           [requestLocal setDelegate:nil];
       }
       requestLocal = nil;
       requestLocal = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:theUrl];
       [requestLocal setDelegate:self];
       [requestLocal setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed)];
       [requestLocal startAsynchronous];
   }

   - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
     {
     requestLocal = nil;
     [self stopLoader];
     UIImage *tempArt = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];
     if (tempArt) {
         self.image = tempArt;
     }
     [data release];
     data = nil;
     }
     -(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
     requestLocal = nil;
     [self stopLoader];
     [data release];
     data = nil;
     }
     @end
5. Then in your ViewComtroller .h import AsycnhronousImageView class and write this

   Make the IBOutlet of your image like this.

   IBOutlet AsycnhronousImageView *image;
6. Change the class in xib AsycnhronousImageView rather than UIImage View
7. Call the following Method

   - (void)loadImageFromFile:(NSString *)filePath;